# IF statement within a loop

Tags: vba, excel

I need help figuring out what I am doing wrong. Keep in my mind im an amateur.

I have two Workbooks, Workbook A and Workbook B. In workbook A I have a value in cell a1 and workbook B i have lets say 10 sheets with values in column A and B.

I would like to match value from a1 in workbook A by looping through all sheets in workbook B, and then returning the address if where it found it. I then write an if statement if the value is found to stop the loop because I will later have it search another cell, though I got stuck so I haven't written that line of code yet.

Here is the code and Ill note where im stuck.

```
sub autocheck()

dim found as varient
dim I as integer
dim val as varient
set val=workbooks("A").worksheets("primary").range("a1").value

For I = 1 to 10
on error resume next
set found=workbooks("b").worksheets(i).range("a:b").match(val)
found= found.address
if isempty(found) then

next i

else 
exit for
end if 

end sub
```

Here I get an error saying can not have next with out for.

Any idea how I get around these? I apologize for the formatting.

Thank you all!

Comment: First of all, delete `On error resume next`. That hides errors, even if the code keeps running, but with errors, that's the first step

Comment: Second, check [DATa TYPES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/data-type-summary). You are using `Variant` types when not needed. Choosing the right type of data helps avoiding errors and also optimizes resources of your PC

Comment: Also, move your `Next i` outside your IF sentence. Put it right after your `End if`. And also, you should check [INDENTATION](http://access-excel.tips/excel-vba-indentation-auto-indent/) when typing code

Comment: @Mitch did you get to test any of the solution provided below ? any feedback ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the if statement is spanning outside the loop. You should just exit the loop with the if statment and keep it contained inside the for

```
    For I = 1 to 10
    on error resume next
    set found=workbooks("b").worksheets(i).range("a:b").match(val)
    found= found.address
    if isEmpty(found) then
    //do something
    else 
    exit for
    end if

    next i



end sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should have "screamed" a few times:

- `dim val as variant` ? maybe as `Variant`.
- You should (or trying) to use `match`, your syntax is closer to `Find`. Using `Find` should also include a scenario `Find` didn't find the result. In any way, you need to `Set` the `Find` function result to a `Range` object.
- Your closing `Next I` should be after the `End If`, not in the middle.
- Using `on error resume next` doesn't make your error go away, you are just "closing your eyes" hoping it will go away.
- More notes in my code's comments below.

***Modified Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub autocheck()

Dim found As Range
Dim foundAdress As String
Dim i As Long
Dim val As Variant

Set val = Workbooks("A").Worksheets("primary").Range("a1").Value

For i = 1 To 10

    Set found = Workbooks("b").Worksheets(i).Range("A:B").Find(what:=val)

    If Not found Is Nothing Then ' Find was successfull
        foundAdress = found.Address
        Exit For
    Else ' Find failed
        ' in your code do nothing, continue looping
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```